# registerTempTable fails on DataFrame created from RDD

Tags: apache-spark

This is in Spark 1.6.x. I'm looking for a workaround.

I have a function that creates a `DataFrame` from a `DataFrame`'s underlying RDD:

```
def rddAndBack(sc: SparkContext, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
}
```

Now I create a couple data frames and register them:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3)).toDF("foo")
val df2 = rddAndBack(sc, df)
df.registerTempTable("df")
df2.registerTempTable("df2")
```

This works:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df")
res23: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [foo: int]
```

But this does not:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df2")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: df2; line 1 pos 14
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
```

This works fine in 2.x but I need to find a workaround in 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you create a new `SQLContext` in your function. Since temporary tables are limited in scope to its parent context, there cannot be accessed from another one.

```
df2.sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df2")
```

To solve this, pass existing `SQLContext` in place of `SparkContext`:

```
def rddAndBack(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, df: DataFrame) = {
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
}
```

or use `getOrCreate` factory method:

```
def rddAndBack(sc: SparkContext, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val sqlContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
}
```

or use `SQLContext` instance bound to the input `df`:

```
def rddAndBack(sc: SparkContext, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val sqlContext = df.sqlContext
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
}
```